# How to save date in Excel in date format

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datetime, datetimepicker

I am working on the winforms.

I want to save the date from datetimepicker in (dd/mm/yyyy ) format to the EXCEL sheet. I managed to save date as 10/10/2010 in  one of the cells of excel sheet.

But when i m trying to read that value from excel sheet into the string what i get is,

```
string dateString ="40461";
```

what i was expecting is ,

```
string dateString ="10/10/2010";
```

Is it possible to convert this string (40461)into the format (10/10/2010) and to display as default time in datetimepicker on form load.

I even tried manually changing format of cell of the excel but didn't work for me.
 any help regarding this issue ?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: How are you getting the value from the cell? Are you using COM interop? Are you using EPPlus?

Comment: Sorry i dont know wats EEPlus..i m using vsto i think that means i m using com interop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
double dateDouble = 40461;  
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dateDouble);

string dateString = dt.ToString();
```